# Getting error Menu_HoverStatic is null or undefined, not a function object, while using asp.net SiteMap control for menu items

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, webresource.axd

Ours is ASP.net application which we recently migrated from Windows 2008 to Windows 2016 server IIS 10.
In Windows 7 OS in IE 11, we face the issue where menu items are not accessible and is throwing error on hover over:(Chrome and Win 10 IE 11 application is working good)

> The value for property 'Menu_HoverStatic' is null or undefined, not a function object.

Event Logs are registering a different error:

> Event message: An error occurred processing a web or script resource request. The resource identifier failed to decrypt.

```
<Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
<Data>IIS APPPOOL\SDMS3AppPool</Data>
<Data>HttpException</Data>
<Data>Unable to validate data.
   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s, Purpose purpose)
   at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

</Data>
    <Data>https://yourdomain.com/WebResource.axd?d=4008OIcfpQF6_PTcMUk_uuvjlbvBEPqjv3TH_Vnn6L3r0AEZJ8Q033KeIIkTHLC_AKyJ_c9JpdqPlJLfGOrxCpK--hZQ1gp-BXe8XbRP_6g1&amp;t=636511268826842555</Data>
    <Data>/WebResource.axd</Data>
```

We call SiteMap in master page:

```
    <div class="NavigationContent">
      <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource"  
        CssClass="Menu"
        
        StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
        DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
        
        StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="MenuItem"
        StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="MenuItemHover" 
        StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="MenuItemSelected"                                    
        
        DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="MenuItem"
        DynamicHoverStyle-CssClass="MenuItemHover" 
        DynamicSelectedStyle-CssClass="MenuItemSelected"                                               
        
        OnDataBound="Menu1_DataBound"
      />                   
      <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />                                    
    </div>
```

Going through google, this error seems to be due to webresource.axd.
I tried following suggestions among many:

> App pool mode set to Integrated, .net 4
>
> Set browser security level to low
>
> Add webresource.axd in IIS handler mapping for application virtual directory.
> [image: Webresource.axd in handler mapping]

Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of suggestions and at last this issue was resolved by machine key.
If your server is a web farm, make sure you have same key in all servers.

```
<system.web>
<machineKey validationKey="2488181654410AFDA27F6A1F4855B75E4E3BD4C7A18969D151A7524CEBE432583762F430B31D86AEEFD368CD2104616C38EABFCBC7C658DA3A553******" decryptionKey="30DC1CA2BD1BDDAB7BFA18DE02B0059443EC656B39FAB179E38CBD82CCF4E***" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto"/>
</system.web>
```

you can follow below article to generate machine key:

[Generate Machine Key In IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey/)